# Le véhicule « écoénergétique » ?

Tags: sens, vocabulaire, adjectifs, terminologie, lexique

Je lis dans un [texte](https://www.lepacte.ca/) qu'on m'invite à m'engager à « réduire ma consommation de pétrole partout où c’est possible [...] ; en choisissant un véhicule écoénergétique si je dois en posséder un ». L'adjectif [*écoénergétique*](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8351877) est formé du mot *économie* et du mot *énergétique* et signifie « qui [économise](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/%C3%A9conomiser) de l'énergie » (GDT) ; je vois en anglais [*energy-efficient*](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8351877#eng). D'autre part on connaît bien l'adjectif [*économique*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/%C3%A9conomique/1) dans le sens de *qui réduit la consommation* ou *qui coûte peu cher*.

---

Peut-on préciser comment *écoénergétique* qualifie le véhicule, *qui économise de l'énergie*, et analyser le sens d'*économie* (*économiser*) qui participe à sa formation ? En quoi cet apport diffère-t-il de celui d'*(véhicule) économique* ; économiser de l'énergie « absolument », est-ce une forme d'euphémisme pour *bien dépenser*, est-ce *avec circonspection* ou avec économie dans un sens plus technique, est-ce le haut *rendement* énergétique ; on peut s'imaginer économiser usuellement de l'énergie en consommant moins, mais comment l'inanimé peut-il faire cette économie alors qu'on l'utilise ; est-ce une référence à l'énergie utilisée lors de la fabrication, à l'assistance d'une autre forme d'énergie (solaire par exemple) lors de l'utilisation ; le terme réfère-t-il plutôt à la conception, à des optimisations techniques comme l'arrêt automatique du moteur lorsqu'une automobile est stationnaire par exemple etc. ; est-ce synonyme de *moderne*, construit selon les *normes* (modernes) ?

Answer (score 1):

Selon la BDL le terme français est l'équivalent de « energy-efficient »; il n'y a dans ce terme pas d'implications sur le plan de l'écologie, pas d'implication sur le plan des responsabilités de l'individu en vertu de quelque devoir social que l'on puisse invoquer. On ne se soucie pas dans la création de ces termes du fait que vous vouliez aller au travail tous les matins en tank qui consomme 80 litres de carburant au 100 kilomètres mais on vous averti que si vous choisissez pour la même importance de tank le dernier modèle qui offre la plus basse de toutes les consommations à 50 litres, alors vous possédez un véhicule « écoénergétique ». Le tout de ce concept réside dans le mot « efficient » qui est l'expression d'un rapport, le rapport « consommation en énergie/service produit », ce que l'on terme spécifiquement *un rendement*. Il me semble qu'il ne faille pas chercher plus loin dans le terme français. Si on espère pouvoir lui imputer des connotations écologiques, on est très mal placé; on aurait peut être aimé penser que la formation eût été faite à partir de « écologie  » et « énergie » mais ce n'est pas de cela qu'il s'agit.

Ce que l'on entend d'habitude par véhicule économique n'est pas certifié dans tous les cas d'utilisation du terme; il y a une certaine ambigüité mais de peu d'importance; on assume dans le contexte courant que l'on ne sacrifie pas le rendement à la dépense et que l'on ajuste le coût au rendement; en d'autres termes cette économie est une économie qui presque toujours est basé sur un critère de rendements égaux. Bien entendu, on peut inclure dans ce rapport des considérations de gain en énergie dans la production du matériel dont le fonctionnement entraine une consommation d'énergie (il sera cependant très souvent très négligeable en rapport à la  totalité, il me semble).

Je verrais maintenant le concept de l'économie absolue comme un changement de direction dans la définition des aspects de l'art d'économiser; il n'est plus question de se baser sur un rendement mais sur le simple concept de la privation et celui de la dépense judicieuse.

Comment: _Le tout de ce concept réside dans le mot « efficient » qui est l'expression d'un rapport, le rapport « consommation en énergie/service produit »._ Larousse en ligne donne qui a un bon rendement pour _efficient_ ou économique pour _fuel efficient_. Si je comprends bien vous dites que c'est l'idée du rendement ici ? Merci !

Comment: @nonobstantfascisme Oui, c'est bien cela; il aurait été mieux de glisser ce terme à proximité comme il identifie spécifiquement le concept.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that there's lots of confusion in French about the 'eco' prefix.  The more traditional meaning refers to economics, but there are lots of modern constructions that refer to ecology instead.  And in this case, you could go either way, or even both at once!

Comment: The lexical entry states it was crafted with _economy_. Your answer hints at something that was also stated in a removed answer, some confusion about the prefix, because it was used to form both economy and ecology, is used to form new words about the environment, but in our case it's about the environment yet formed with economy. Nobody discussed how _écolo_ could be used. The word may denote a shift in the lexical relationship to tie up economy and ecology oriented things. Thanks!

Comment: Totally agree that there could be a lot of deliberate obfuscation with using this confusing form.  'ecolo' tends to be more of a familiar abbreviation for ecologique, not necessarily good in formal documents like the original.  But one could surely specify 'econo-' or 'ecolo-' if one wanted to be precise or to choose one over the other.  In defense of the writers, those 2 concepts do tend to go together on the whole though

Comment: There could well be a difference (read:  huge gap) between the Quebec version and the French one of all those things..